# Need to get the total and discount calculated on a table row via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to calculate totals and the discount amounts on the following table.

```
<tbody id="generate_invoice_table">                     
    <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>Glass Polish Normal</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control text-right quantity" value="1"></td>
    <td class="price">8000.00</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control text-right discount"></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled="" class="form-control text-right amount"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked="" name="check-invoice"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

So basically, I want to enter quantity and then the discount and show the amount at the last input box.
The Javascript is given below, I get the message `trs.find` is not a function...

```
$('#invoice').delegate('.quantity,.price,.discount', 'keyup', function () {
            var t = document.getElementById("generate_invoice_table");//find table data
            var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            var qty = trs.find('.quantity').val();
            var price = trs.find('.price').val();
            var dis = trs.find('.discount').val();
            varamt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
            trs.find('.amount').val(amt);
            total();//calculate total and show after the invoice table
        });


    });
    function total() {
        var t = 0;
        $('.amount').each(function (i, e) {
            varamt = $(this).val() - 0;
            t += amt;
        });
        $('.total').html(t);
    }
```

Comment: That's what happens when you mix jQuery methods with native methods randomly. Use one or the other. You are trying to use a jQuery method `find()` on a collection that isn't a jQuery object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete line with `var t=` and try to replace the next line whit this code:

```
var trs = $("#generate_invoice_table tr");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I got it to work, however, I have several of these rows, how can I apply for each row...?Now when i change quantity other row amount change...:(

Comment: trs is an array of elements, so you'll can access each row inside a loop like this `trs[i].find()`, etc.

Comment: Also you can identity the row where the keyup event fired up and start from that point

Comment: issue still remains:for(i=0;i<=trs_length;i++){
                    var qty = trs[i].find('.quantity').val();
                    var price = trs[i].find('.price').val();
                    var dis = trs[i].find('.discount').val();
                    var amt = (qty * price) - (qty * price * dis) / 100;
                    trs[i].find('.amount').val(amt);
                    total();//calculate total and show after the invoice table

                }

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned it's bettter to choso what you gonna use pure JS or jQuery. On example below there are `onkeyup` events on discount and quantity inputs. In event handler `recalc()` price, quantity and discount are read using `document.getElementById` selectors. The amount calculated and inserted into appropriate input.

`amt` count I took without changes.

```js
function recalc() {

  var price = Number(document.getElementById('price').innerText);
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('quantity').value);
  var discount = Number(document.getElementById('discount').value);
  
  var total = '';
  if (price && quantity) {
    total = discount ? ((quantity * price) - (quantity * price * discount) / 100) : (quantity * price);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('amount').value = total;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="generate_invoice_table">                     
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>Glass Polish Normal</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control text-right quantity" value="1" onkeyup="recalc()">
    </td>
    <td class="price">
      <span id="price">8000.00</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="discount" class="form-control text-right discount" onkeyup="recalc()">
      </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" disabled="" id="amount" class="form-control text-right amount">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="" name="check-invoice">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, the table is dynamically loaded thats why i have put classes since the id is unique. need to see how to include your function to a identified row in the table...since now all the values change, and id should be unique too...

Comment: For instance, you could navigate by `name` attribute or look for appropriate elements as nested of `generate_invoice_table`